# which Visual Studio version is the earliest one to support 64bit compilation?

Tags: visual-studio

is it `Visual Studio 2005`?

The reason why I ask is because I've inherited some old code (written with VS 6) that now needs to be compiled to run on a 64bit system. Unfortunately the code won't compile with VS 2010 so I'm trying to use the oldest possible version.

Comment: Hmmm, isn't a better aproach to try fix the errors assuming todays compiler is much better in detecting flaws in your source code? Your approach might save you time now, but it will bite you in the long run.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deeptanshuv/archive/2006/04/11/573795.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181213/how-to-build-a-solution-to-target-64-bit-environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS2002 (v7.0) was the earliest, tho I'd recommend VS2003 (v7.1). You may have issues installing either one on Win 7 tho.